# CSS keep image in ::before from expanding past the pseudo-element

Tags: css, image, overflow, pseudo-element

I have a little mark at the bottom right of my own [code snippet page](https://www.lampe2020.de/codeschnipsel), which should also contain my website's favicon. I want to use `::before` for this but I have no clue how to resize the image to stay inside the `1em` by `1em` pseudo-element.

```css
div#snippet {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(200,200,200,0.3);
}

a#l2020-link {
  color: blue;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  border: 0px solid grey;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 3px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direcion: row;
}
a#l2020-link::before {
  content: url(https://www.lampe2020.de/favicon.ico);
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="snippet">
  <!-- Imagine the code inputs and the iFrame to show the result here -->
  <a href="https://www.lampe2020.de/" id="l2020-link">Lampe2020.de</a>
</div>
```

I want the favicon to be fully visible but shrunk down to `1em` by `1em`.
I've tried CSS `object-fit` but it had absolutely null effect on the image no matter what I set it to. `overflow: hidden` or `overflow: clip` kinda work but they obviously just cut off what's too much of the image and don't resize the image to fit.

Comment: use it as background instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the content to "" and use background-image instead, and set the background-size to 1em.

```css
div#snippet {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(200,200,200,0.3);
}

a#l2020-link {
  color: blue;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  border: 0px solid grey;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 3px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direcion: row;
}
a#l2020-link::before {
  content:"";
  background-image: url(https://www.lampe2020.de/favicon.ico);
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  background-size:1em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="snippet">
  <!-- Imagine the code inputs and the iFrame to show the result here -->
  <a href="https://www.lampe2020.de/" id="l2020-link">Lampe2020.de</a>
</div>
```